# Indirect jmp instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, att

In assembly AT&T syntax, we can perform a indirect jmp using `*`
However I could not understand why following code snippets are different.

```
mov $main, %eax
jmp *%eax
```

and

```
jmp *main
```

where main is a label.

Can anyone please explain the difference between these two?

Comment: Because you used a `$` in the first case, to make the combination of those two instructions like `jmp main`.  Also, the second code block isn't a valid instruction; `mov` needs two operands.

Comment: `*` only has a meaning in AT&T syntax when used with `jmp` / `call`.  Did you mean `jmp *main`, i.e. `mov main, %eax` / `jmp *%eax`, loading a new EIP value from memory at the specified addressing mode?  AT&T needs `*` to disambiguate that because it unfortunately uses plain `main` as a memory operand rather than an address in any context except a jump/call.

Comment: Yes, I meant jmp *main, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: `jmp *main` behaves like `mov main, %eax; jmp *%eax`.  Note the missing dollar sign.

Comment: So it's fetching the content at the address specified by the main symbol and then loading the EIP with it.